# Не выводится результат парсинга

Tags: python

Пытаюсь спарсить Яндекс страницу, а именно взять ссылки на сайты, которые предлагает Яндекс.
Но парсится он через раз. Например сейчас при запуске он выводит теги, а при следующем запуске:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

В чем проблема? Это капча вылезает?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
# pip install beautifulsoup4
# pip install lxml

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)    # Получим метод Response
    r.encoding = 'utf8'
    return r.text   # Вернем данные объекта text

def get_divs(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    divs = soup.findAll('li', {'class': ['serp-item']})
    for i in divs:
        cols = i.find_all('a', {'class': ['link link_theme_normal organic__url link_cropped_no i-bem']})
        print(cols)




a = get_divs(get_html('https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC&lr=39'))
```

Сам запрос:
https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC&lr=39

Хочу спарсить ссылки, предлагаемые Яндексом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, если вы посмотрите `html`, который получаете, то увидите, что там капча:

```
<div class="captcha-wrapper">...
<div class="captcha i-bem">...
<div class="captcha__image">...
<div class="captcha__play-button">...
<div class="captcha__play">...
<div class="captcha__play-image">...
<div class="captcha__play-text">...
```

Картинка капчи, которая вышла у меня:

[image: captcha]

Comment: а если менять user-agent каждый запрос, обойдет ли это капчу? Или если менять ip?

Comment: @Евгений На какое-то время может помочь, пробуйте